# How to make the value of li tag hidden using javaScript or Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I have a list of letters, each one of those letters is inside a li tag :

```
<ul>
    <li class="letter">A</li>
    <li class="letter">B</li>
    <li class="letter">C</li>
    <li class="letter">D</li>
</ul>
```

The question is how to make those letters (A,B,C,D) hidden without hide the li tag itself, because it already have a style and I don't want to lose it..
and  how to make them visible using javaScript function?

PS: the list is created by javaScript function :

```
                var ul = document.createElement('ul');
                ul.setAttribute('id','letters');
                var txt = txtword.value;
                var t, tt;
                var word = new Array();

                for (i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
                    word[i] = txt[i];


                document.getElementById('answer_div').appendChild(ul);
                word.forEach(wordletters);

                function wordletters(element, index, arr) {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.setAttribute('class','item');

                    ul.appendChild(li);

                    t = document.createTextNode(element);

                    li.innerHTML=li.innerHTML + element;
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple add `display:none;` it will be hide only

Comment: display:none will hide the li tag, but I want it still visible .. I want to hide the letter only

Comment: if he put display non it will also hide the li tag , the op is looking to hide only the letters A,B,C,D

Comment: you can define a swap function and extend the element and then each time it get value of the element put it in that extended new member variable and set the cur value to empty and next time it checks if the cur value is empty then it get from the extended property "li.__value_ = ""; .

Answer (score 0):

Consider `visibility` property:

```css
.letter:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="letter">A</li>
  <li class="letter">B</li>
  <li class="letter">C</li>
  <li class="letter">D</li>
</ul>
```

Or consider a small width with some oveflow trick if you want to keep the bullet.

```css
li {
 list-style:inside;
}

.letter:nth-child(2) {
  width:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="letter">A</li>
  <li class="letter">B</li>
  <li class="letter">C</li>
  <li class="letter">D</li>
</ul>
```

Then simply use a class that you can add/remove with JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.letter')[2].classList.add('hide');
```

```css
li {
 list-style:inside;
}

.hide{
  width:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="letter">A</li>
  <li class="letter">B</li>
  <li class="letter">C</li>
  <li class="letter">D</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul>
        <li class="letter"><input style="display:none;" type="text" id="A" value="A"></li>
        <li class="letter"><input style="display:none;" type="text" id="B" value="B"></li>
        <li class="letter"><input style="display:none;" type="text" id="C" value="C"></li>
        <li class="letter"><input style="display:none;" type="text" id="D" value="D"></li>
    </ul>
```

You can use to show li data by below function.

```
function show_li_data(id){
$("#"+id).show();
}
```

Comment: this solution is true, but I'm sorry  I didn't explain the whole problem .. I've updated the problem .. please answer it if you have an idea, Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to apply action on this action you call this function(when you want to show lista data).

Comment: Sorry, but  the list itself create after calling this function.. the function create a number of li tags exactly the same number that the user has entered in an input text ..
so, how to add a span as a child of the li tag .. using the function above(in my question)

Comment: You can user `<span>` tag intead of hidden text.

Comment: yes I know, but how to make it create automatically inside the li tag using the function above ( the function in question) ?

Comment: `$('ul').append('<li class="letter"><input style="display:none;" type="text" id="D" value="D"></li>');`

Comment: sorry, but letters are not static, the user is who enter them, and the function above create a li tag for each letter, what I want  is make the letter inside a span tag instead of li tag .. I hope you understand me

Comment: `$('ul').append('<li class="letter"><span>D</span></li>');` Try this.

Comment: you use the letter "D", but  I told you that the user who will type in the letters not me, so I used the function above to create a list of the letters that the user has entered in a text input .. look at the function above to understand me

Comment: I just give you a scenario for your requirement not whole code.For this you have to decide which type of value you will decide for the data.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it you can simply wrap the A,B,C,D inside a span like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="letter"><span>A<span></li>
    <li class="letter"><span>B<span></li>
    <li class="letter"><span>C<span></li>
    <li class="letter"><span>D<span></li>
</ul>
```

and then

```
li span{
display:none
}
```

Here is the the codepen :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEmJLP

Comment: this solution is true, but I'm sorry I didn't explain the whole problem .. I've updated the problem .. please answer it if you have an idea, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have modified the answer.Try using text-indent; In your case just add this:

style="text-indent:-9999px;" in each li tag

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
                function wordletters(element, index, arr) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.setAttribute('class','item');

                ul.appendChild(li);
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                li.appendChild(span);


                span.innerHTML=span.innerHTML + element;
            }
```

This function will create a span inside the li tag, so I can hide the span without hide the li tag ..

Thank you everyone for your time ^_^

Answer (score -2):

You should select this elements by their class name, and set display:none.

document.getElementByClassName("letter").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementByClassName("letter").style.display = 'block'

Comment: if he put display non it will also hide the li tag , the op is looking to hide only the letters A,B,C,D